# How do i get my id field to show up in the request data when updating multiple records?

Tags: cakephp, input, hidden

Datasource: Array source (Open source code)

I have a __getTable method that loads the data from a configuration file to an array that looks like this:

[image]

I created a method that takes in data in this form and creates a table out of it. The table creates a column in the row for every field present in the given data array except for id. id is a hidden field and the code generated by the input function looks like this:

[image]

but shows up like this when inspecting the code in firebug:

[image]

Ignore all except for what is in the control-group division.

Since im using the array source, i create my own update method and have to call updateAll() in my controller to call the method. All the data i need is in the request data except for the id! why, and how can i fix this? It looks like this:

[image]

The rest of the information on here might not be necessary but ill post it just in case.

[image: Method code, the types aren't filled in automatically, hence the default type]

[image: How the method code looks]

[image: Controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Most of it was unique to my code though. There was a bug where i call the $this->Widget->input function. I use index rather than the id and that screws up my tabs. each data array passed in to the function had indexs from 0-~11 and so the values were overriding each other since the submit was for multiple tabs. Also i have a function 'open' that opens a table and the rows were specified to have 4 columns rather than 5 and id was the 5th column.